# Best javascript frameworks for rails app backend UI design

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, extjs

Which are the best frameworks that better integrates with Rails to easily develop RIA backends?

In different projects I've used, beside others, jQuery and Sencha Extjs (with various working or nearly working gems that tried to integrate rails and the javascript).

I've highlighted those two frameworks because in my opinion are the Alpha and Omega of frameworks that could be used:

- jQuery is well known and documented but it has the basics controls that should be assembled to provide a decent dashboard,
- Sencha ExtJs gave me the impression that I was just rewriting the entire application, adding a layer of unwanted complexity.

So the question is: is there anything that sits in the middle of the two?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try http://dojotoolkit.org/

It has a lot of controls like Charts, Grids, RichText editors , diffrent layout controls etc..
You can check their demo site http://dojotoolkit.org/features/graphics-and-charting

Comment: It looks very interesting but before I accept your answer I want to understand why all dojo + rails gems have ceased to be updated long time ago.

Comment: I cant really help you with that, I use dojo with asp.net lately, but drails should work.